# Docker Desktop won't pull image

Tags: docker, windows-10, wsl-2

After updating Docker Desktop to the latest version (v4.14.1), pulling images from Docker Hub no longer works, although I am logged in.

```
> docker pull alpine
Using default tag: latest
[2022-11-25T15:24:57.304539600Z][docker-credential-desktop][W] Windows version might not be up-to-date: The system cannot find the file specified.
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for alpine, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I've performed the login using the cli too, but still, the same `Windows version might not be up-to-date` error pops up.

Answer (score 6):

Well, apparently at some point, Docker decided to change the name of the credentials' provider variable in the `~/.docker/config.json` from `credsStore` to `credStore`. So the correct config file should be:

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.in/v1/": {}
  },
  "credStore": "desktop.exe"
}
```